# Error: 'ARIMAResults' object has no attribute 'plot_predict'

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, arima

I'm running this code using `sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA` on my time series data

```
model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(df.Sales, order=(1,1,1))
model_fit = model.fit()
print(model_fit.summary())

# Actual vs Fitted
model_fit.plot_predict(dynamic=False)
plt.show()
```

When I tried to plot the results, it gave me this error:

'ARIMAResults' object has no attribute 'plot_predict'

My version of `statsmodels.__version__` is '0.13.2'

Answer (score 1):

Statsmodels version 13 removed the `.plot_predict()` method from the `ARIMA` classes. Hence, you only need to use `plot_predict()` that you already imported into your code. Here is an example:

```py
plot_predict(model_fit, dynamic=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_predict`